# All possible combinations from a matrix

Tags: matrices

I would like to get all possible combinations from a matrix as follows:

$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\
a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}
\end{bmatrix},
$$
The formula says: $$\hat \pi=\sigma_1*a_{11}*a_{21}*a_{31}+\sigma_2*a_{11}*a_{21}*a_{32}+\sigma_3*a_{11}*a_{21}*a_{33}+\sigma_4*a_{11}*a_{22}*a_{31}+\sigma_5*a_{11}*a_{22}*a_{32}+\sigma_6*a_{11}*a_{22}*a_{33}+\cdots.
$$
For an `nxm` matrix, I figured out that we have $m^n$ possible combination (we have $27$ sigmas for a `3x3` matrix).

How to write this formula in general? Like $$\sum_{s\in I}\prod_{p\in J}a_{sp}\sigma_{p}???$$

Comment: Do you mean the determinant of the matrix?

Comment: No I want to multiply the element of the matrix.

Comment: What is $\sigma?$

Comment: It is just a number that counts how many combinations (products) do we have. For example if we have a $2\times2$ matrix $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$. I want to calculate: $ac\sigma_1+ad\sigma_2+bc\sigma_3+bd\sigma_4$. For a $3\times3$ matrix I gave the example in the question.

Comment: In your $2 \times 2$ example, what are the values of $\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3$ and $\sigma_4$?  Are you aware of the "big sum" formula for the determinant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B$ be the set of all $n$-tuples of positive integers not exceeding $m$, i.e.

$$B=\{(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n)\ |\ b_i\in\{1,2,\ldots, m\}\}$$

If $b\in B$ is an $n$-tuple, $b_i$ will denote its $i$-th component. Clearly, we can use these tuples to index the given coefficients $\sigma$, instead of using integers. In particular, integer $k$ will correspond to tuple $b=(b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n)$ with $$b_i=1+\left(\left\lfloor\frac{k-1}{m^{n-i}}\right\rfloor\bmod{m}\right)$$

In your example of $3\times 3$ matrix, this replaces $\sigma_1$ by $\sigma_{(1,1,1)}$ and $\sigma_2$ by $\sigma_{(1,1,2)}$ and so on.

Then, your desired sum can be expressed as $$\Large\sum_{b\in B}\left(\sigma_b\prod_{i=1}^n a_{i,b_i}\right)$$

Strictly speaking, the trick of replacing integers by $n$-tuples is purely cosmetic. It is possible to use the integers as well; it's just the resulting expression will be more messy. We could also write the sum as
$$\Large\sum_{k\in\{1,2,\ldots,m^n\}}\left(\sigma_k\prod_{i=1}^n a_{i,{1+\left(\left\lfloor\frac{k-1}{m^{n-i}}\right\rfloor\bmod{m}\right)}}\right)$$

If the coefficients $\sigma$ are arbitrary, this is as good as it gets. If they have some additional structure, it might be possible to simplify the expression further.

Comment: What do you mean by: $\dfrac{k-1}{m^{n-i}}\mod m$? For example, when $m=n=3$ and $k=2$ how to calculate $\prod_{i=1}^{3}a_{i,\dfrac{2-1}{3^{3-i}}\mod 3}=a_{1,\dfrac{1}{9}\mod 3}\cdot a_{2,\dfrac{1}{3}\mod 3}\cdot a_{3,\dfrac{1}{1}\mod 3}$?
$$\dfrac{1}{9}\mod 3=??$$

Comment: The implied division was meant to be integer-based one (i.e. take just the quotient and forget about remainder). I'll adjust the answer to make it more explicit using the $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$  function. Thus, $\frac{1}{9}$ would become $0$, $\frac{1}{3}$ would become $0$ and $\frac{1}{1}$ would be $1$. Adding $1$ to each of them would yield tuple $(1,1,2)$.

Comment: OK. That make sense for me now. I appreciate your help. Thanks.